# Retrieve all key-value pairs from properties file in Spring Boot with a given prefix and suffix

Tags: spring-boot, properties-file

I have been trying for sometime now. I want to read from the properties file and store as a hashmap.

Here is an example.

```
sample.properties
pref1.pref2.abc.suf = 1
pref1.pref2.def.suf = 2
...
...
```

Here is the Config class.

```
@ConfiguraionProperties
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:sample.properties")
public class Config{
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public HashMap<String, Integer> getAllProps(){
        //TO-DO 
    }
}
```

I want to be able to return `{"abc":1, "def":2};`

I stumbled upon answers like using `PropertySources`, `AbstractEnvironment` etc., but still can't get my head around using it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Spring Boot 2.0 has the new Binder API which I think does what you want. Look it up. For older Spring Boot versions there might be something similar but less flexible/clean.

Comment: @jhyot thanks, will take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

The class

```
org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.EnvironmentEndpoint
```

reads all configured properties and puts them in a Map.
This is used to return all properties and their values from a REST endpoint. See [production ready endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html)

You can copy the 3 methods that build the Map with all properties from class EnvironmentEndpoint into your own. Then just iterate over the Map and select all properties by their key.

I have done that in one project, worked quite well.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using spring boot  @component, @PropertySource and @ConfigurationProperties

Create a component like:

```
@Component
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:filename.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "pref1")
public class Properties{
/**
*should be same in properties pref1.pref2.abc.suf = 1
*It will give u like abc.suf = 1 , def.suf = 2
*/
private Map<String,String> pref2; 

//setter getter to use another place//

    public Map<String, String> getPref2() {
        return pref2;
    }

    public void setPref2(Map<String, String> pref2) {
        this.pref2= pref2;
    }
}

Use in other class suing @autowired

public class PropertiesShow{
@Autowired
private  Properties properties;

public void show(){

 System.out.println(properties.getPref2());
}
}
```

Comment: It is not working for me